# Logic Level MOSFET IRLZ44N - under Wemos mini

Tags: mosfet, logic-level

I used IRLZ44N with Arduino Nano in order to dimm a 12v LED strip.

When tried to use it with Wemos Mini - I get only 7.6v max ( when controlling a 12v source ).

Probing the output pin (`D3` ) - voltage is 3.3v, meaning it is at its max.

Is it due to different Logic Level ( 5v for Arduino ) ?

If so - is there a way to use this MOSFET for same application ?

** EDIT 1 ** Adding Schematic pic

Schematic is same, except:

1) Wemos Mini instead of Arduino

2) Load is LED strip , not a motor.

[image]

Comment: Please post the schematic.

Comment: As it stands right now only you know what the schematic for your circuit looks like. You will likely get more support if you can share that schematic in your question and bolster that with a bit more circuit description.

Comment: The lowest voltage for which Rds(on) is specified is 4V and Vgs(th) is specified as between 1 and 2V, so your results are not really surprising. It *is* specified for operation at 5V Vgs so it is very probable that the different drive voltage is the issue.

Comment: What's this 0-60V- you connecting to GND? Are applying AC or DC?

Comment: @Huisman - it refers as DC in range between 0-60

Comment: Sounds like you need a 3.3 V capable Vgsth MOSFET instead, or an NPN.